# The strange story of Lord Lefthide

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, steganography

Lord Lefthide was found dead in his mansion, to what it would seem of a heart attack. But it appears that moments before his death, he was writing some uncanny childish story. He was indeed found dead at his desk with a pen in his hand and the following note in front of him:

> "That wretch ! He still watches for me", the  bunny says.
>   Old, browsing the site, the patient hunter embraces the shadows
>   "Nobody is immortal, especially not you, bunny!"
>
> Fearless little bunny, he nonetheless hides beneath a shrubbery.
>   "Great human, hunting's forbidden! Drop your searches!", he cries,
>   "The tide is rising, stop this madness at once!"
>
> "What an insanity!", says the lurking man, "The sea is set one mile away!"
>   He stops, most of his body is moistening.
>   "Indeed, in water I dwell..."

What truly killed Lord Lefthide ?

**Hint 1**

> The three verses are separated for a reason, and they all have a common point.

**Hint 2**

> The name of the Lord is definitely a red herring, sorry for that. Still, it's an interesting anagram of someone's name linked to this puzzle.

**Hint 3**

> The answer to [A most curious story about something stolen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62179/a-most-curious-story-about-something-stolen)

Comment: Does this require any specific knowledge/trivia?

Comment: Not necessarily I'd say, although it can help

Comment: the bunny is a bunny transported from Minecraft and is actually the rare Killer Bunny... dun dun dun

Comment: Would a steganography tag be appropriate here?

Comment: The grammar seems a little off. For example line 4, that he seems kind of random. Also, what is the old in line 2 describing or is it part of the riddle?

Comment: @North It's true that steganohgraphy fits, thank you. As for the grammar, well, Lord Lefthide seemed to be somewhat disturbed at this moment.

Comment: A hint was added

Comment: The common thread may be the internet, since all three verses have language that suggests on-line activity ("browsing the site", "searches", "lurking").  But I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: Another possible common thread is the moon.  1) the immortal Moon Rabbit from Asian folklore, 2) "The tide is rising", and 3) Maria (meaning seas) are major features on the moon.  Again, I'm just stabbing in the dark - no idea where to go with this.

Comment: @Pugmonkey You're so far from it :)

Comment: Aah the Moon Rabbit. Brings back good memories. :)

Comment: Is another hint forthcoming, @Keelhaul ?

Comment: @Phylyp You're greedy aren't you :D ? Anyway, I added one

Comment: Ooh, I'm getting nowhere with this! :-) @Keelhaul

Comment: @Phylyp And so I added another hint, but the Rand al'Thor way :p

Comment: After seeing the accepted answer, I'm afraid this puzzle was smack in the middle of the "unsolvable, and impossible to know that it is unsolvable" territory for most people. That's the most disappointing kind of puzzle, since the harder you try, the more you will be punished, and in the end, when the answer is finally revealed, you'll know for certain that all your efforts were without any hope of success, right from the beginning. To avoid such puzzles in the future, please at least add the knowledge (or trivia) tag to alert the would-be solver of such a possibility.

Comment: @Bass Thank you for pointing this issue, but I mostly disagree. My idea was that one could get the idea of interpolating the paragraphs and picking words periodically by noticing some odd things (same number of letters, weird grammar, words that stand out from the context). The obtained verses clearly point to a lovecraftian vibe, or at least can be quickly googled. Though the connection to the song can definitely help and is the cherry on the cake, it is not needed to the overall resolution of the puzzle. Of course, I may have underestimated its base complexity :)

Comment: It's also a bit strange that hint #2 says the Lord's name is a red herring, when it isn't. Indeed, the name is precisely what led to the breakthrough.

Comment: @Statman The name is Lefthide, and there is nothing hidden in some left part of the riddle, hence the red herring. I specifically said it was however an interesting anagram, but I though more of it as a trivia (I just had to find a name, and came up with this "easter egg")

Comment: @Keelhaul Ah, that does make much more sense now. I never thought about the surface reading implying something hidden on the left. It's appropriate at this time of year that your Easter egg led to the solution :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Answer**

> Clued in by @Gustavo-Gabriel we know that Lefthide is an anagram for Hetfield, the last name of James Hetfield, the songwriter for the band Metallica.  The suspect is confirmed with the lyrics of the Metallica song “The Thing That Should Not Be”.  The main chorus of the song holds the similarities:
>
>  Fearless wretch
>  Insanity
>  He watches
>  Lurking beneath the sea
>  Great old one
>  Forbidden site
>  He searches
>  Hunter of the shadows is rising
>  Immortal
>  In madness you dwell
>
>   Indeed if we use the third hint, we find that each word comes from reading each third word in successive paragraphs going from the 2nd, then 1st, then 3rd paragraph, and repeating.
>
>  **Theories**
>  I’ve tried to look at different patterns in the remaining words - nothing so far, but there may be some other steganography relating to the *common point* from the first hint.  Perhaps we’re supposed to look for “the thing that should not be”.
>
>  The song is strongly influenced by the stories of [H.P. Lovecraft](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft) an American horror fiction writer. The answer could be the same way that Lovecraft died - Cancer of the small intestine and malnutrition.
>
>  Another possibility would be to look more in depth into the meaning behind the lyrics or to find more clues in Lovecraft’s stories that could lead to a solution.  For an example possible lead, a quote from Wikipedia about Lovecraft’s novel [The Call of Cthulhu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Call_of_Cthulhu) (which is featured heavily in the song) reads “After finishing the manuscript, Thurston realizes he is now a target of Cthulhu's worshippers”, although I don’t think this is correct.

Comment: That is a superb find! But I'd be quite disappointed if the mystery unfolded just to find the message "It was malnutrition!" `;)`

Comment: Well done! No need to go really far into theories, what you found describes what killed him: rot13(Gur Guvat Gung Fubhyq Abg Or), which is rot13(Pguhyuh), or more broadly rot13(N Ybirpensgvna ubeebe). It is broad enough to allow multiple answers of that kind though, the most important part being finding what you found ;).

Comment: Also, I edited your answer to add the spoiler tags

Comment: Wow, when I said Hetfield I didn't think it was related to James Hetfield, I should have investigated the songs more. And I am a big Metallica fan :(

Answer (score 5):

I'm not too certain but I believe the answer is:

> The letter C somehow

Explanation:

> There are three verses each with 3 lines. C is the third letter of the alphabet. Each verse has some reference to the verb "to see" or "the sea". "Watches", "Searches", and "The Sea"

Comment: I'm not sure this is the full answer either, but it looks like a good start! Well spotted! Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: Sadly, this is not it, not even close :p

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a full answer (yet), but I noticed a few things:

Hint 1:

> I think the verses' common point is that they each have **27 words**.

Hint 2:

> Not entirely clear, but we have reason to believe the anagram is James **Hetfield**. (Thanks, @gustavo-gabriel!) So, maybe Metallica-related?

Hint 3:

> The clue from the answer is **3**.

EDIT:
Not sure where to go from here, based on OP's comment. May need another hint.

Comment: I thought hint 2 was the anagram LeftHide = Hetfield, but couldnt find any user related, only Metallica's singer xD

Comment: There's also a Swedish music producer and DJ who goes by "The Field," but I can't find anything that relates to the puzzle, unfortunately.

Comment: I also tried to make sense of Cliff Burton's (Linked to Hetfield) death and the numbers 27 and 3 that you found, but with no luck...

Comment: Still not too cose, but there's improvement... also in the comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Trial for an answer

> Lefthide **ate** something and died?

Clues:

> Based on the hint given, I counted the number of words between each commas and other punctuations and thus they are: 
>  [image] 
>  Based on this, we can deduce that **8** is the number missing and so something that Lefthide **ate(8)** must have killed him...

Comment: You're faaaar from it :)

Comment: For what it's worth, 9 and 0 are also missing.