# A most curious story about something stolen

Tags: riddle, word

*The answer to this puzzle is a hint for [The strange story of Lord Lefthide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61778/the-strange-story-of-lord-lefthide?noredirect=1#comment189126_61778).*

> Several horsemen came across a German man. "Have you seen some twins?", they asked him.
>   The man answered by the negative, then added: "May I know why you're looking for them?"
>   "We call them the Scorpion Brothers, they have stolen something quite unique a week ago, while the guards were busy playing dice.", they answered.
>   "What did they steal?"
>   "That which is missing, of course!"

What was stolen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea how it can be stolen, but looks like what is missing is

> **three**

Looking at various parts of the story, there are places which hint, directly or indirectly, at similar entities, reordered:

> unique (1), twins (2), horsemen (4, of the apocalyptic variety), May (5th month), dice (6 sides), week (7 days), scorpio (8th zodiac sign), "nein" (9, German for "no")

Couldn't find anything related to the missing one in between, so that might be what they stole.

Comment: "A week ago" could probably refer to 7 by similar reasoning with 7 days in a week.

Comment: @Syluxdoomangle ah, very much so! I had the number written down, but couldn't find the reason anymore!

Comment: I just realized I made a terrible mistake, I (slightly) edited my question, you should have no trouble fixing your answer :)

Comment: That was quick, especially considering my initial mistake! But this was only a hint to the other, more obscure, riddle...

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this is the actual answer, but how about they stole themselves? After all, it *is* the twins that are missing, hence the searching for them.

Comment: Now that I think about it, we're told they stole something *unique*, and they're twins, so they aren't unique. Good try, though!

Comment: A valid point :)