# What is a Lefthide Word™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>

---

If a word satisfies a certain property, it is called an Lefthide Word™. Use the example word lists below to find the rule. Each word can be tested for whether it is an Lefthide Word™ without depending on other words in these lists.

Note that font and capitalization do not matter.

| Lefthide Words™ | Not Lefthide Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WINDOW | DOOR |
| TRUE | TRUTH |
| NOTHING | SOMETHING |
| FIRE | FIERCE |
| WAIT | WAITING |
| HERO | VILLAIN |
| MAMA | MOM |
| ASTRONOMY | STAR |
| DAMAGE | DAMAGED |
| ENTER | LEAVE |
| SWEET | CANDY |
| GOD | ANGEL |

CSV version:

```
Lefthide Words™, Not Lefthide Words™
WINDOW,DOOR
TRUE,TRUTH
NOTHING,SOMETHING
FIRE,FIERCE
WAIT,WAITING
HERO,VILLAIN
MAMA,MOM
ASTRONOMY,STAR
DAMAGE,DAMAGED
ENTER,LEAVE
SWEET,CANDY
GOD,ANGEL
```

*There are a lot more Lefthide words, these are just a few.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given [the strange story of Lord Lefthide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61778/the-strange-story-of-lord-lefthide/62283) and Gustavo Gabriel's contribution to its solution, it seems likely (and the ones I've checked are consistent with this) that a Lefthide Word is

> one that occurs in the title of a Metallica song.

Comment: Yes, you got it ;)

Comment: Damn! Just beat me to it.

Comment: If only I had seen this riddle earlier... :p

Comment: @Keelhaul Yeah, I was hoping you wouldn't see this, or it would be answered in 2 minutes ;)